# Code review tools for xcode (Objective c)?

Tags: xcode, clang

I have been searching for code review tools for xcode that can check standard coding conventions eg.(camel casing, function naming, indentation etc) on the editor itself. After searching for a while I found one plugin for xcode8.x (https://github.com/mapbox/XcodeClangFormat) that can be use to indent the code, correct spacing etc. Can anyone suggest any tool to check naming conventions and other coding convention checks?

Comment: This question is off-topic (Recommended to find an offsite resource). However to answer your question, you can use OCLint